# Нужно ли выделять запятыми "действительно"?

Tags: пунктуация

**Вот что дейтвительно нуждается в исправлении - это возможность разворачиваться...**
/"действительно" решил не выделять, тире, кажется, на месте, всё верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, "действительно" здесь не выделяется запятыми. Это не вводное слово, а как бы усиливающие слова (=в действительности, на самом деле). Но слово "вот" здесь лишнее, нарушает структуру фразы.

Comment: Добавив союз "а" в начале, по контексту: "...(А) Вот что дейтвительно нуждается в исправлении...", я улучшу ситуацию?

Comment: Пожплуй,да

Comment: Правильно: Что действительно нуждается в исправлении, так это возможность...